# Re-do versioning of a small project?

Tags: version-control, release, versioning

I am working on a project which will be released to a larger team but so far I'm the main person working on it. I'm consulting with one or two other people who have pulled the code but I'm the only person who's written the code.

I started with the code at v0.0.0 but after some changes bumped it to v1.0.0 and have made some minor version increments since then.

Now I'm realizing that I haven't released the code yet and the public API is not stable. I think it would make more sense for the version of my project to drop below 1.0.0 down into 0.x.y. What is a good way to do this?

I'm using git for version control. This is a python project so on each commit the version is recorded in the main `__init__.py` file. I've also tagged merges into the `main` branch that increment the version with the version number.

Is there any way I can reset the version numbering below `0.0.0` and release at `1.0.0`, or at this point should I just continue incrementing versions in `1.x.y` and bump to `2.0.0` when the public api becomes stable and the project is released?

I could easily delete the existing `1.x.y` tags and reset the version in `__init__.py` down to the version I think it should be at, but I can't rewrite the git history to change the version listed in `__init__.py` for the old commits.

I don't have much experience versioning/releasing code in this sort of controlled format...

Comment: Just continue incrementing from version 1.x.y.